# wget as background task followed by successive background tasks

Tags: php, background, task, wget, shell-exec

I am trying to do this from PHP - basically download a jpg from a remote location and resize it if necessary. The second task isn't that important, but what I do want is for the second task to wait for the wget to be successfully completed, but for them BOTH to run in the background sequentially and not hold up the PHP thread as the task is not immediately of importance for PHP, it's for caching purposes:

```
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic1.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic1.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic1_reduced.jpg) &');
```

However what happens with the above is that PHP hangs until both tasks are finished (why, given the & suffix?)

If I use the `wget -b` switch (though why need to do that if I am already using &?) then it does run as a background task, but the second task (`convert`) fails because the wget task is now on a different thread and it tries to convert a file that has not yet been (fully) downloaded.

Oh, and if I just do:

```
(wget -q -O /tmp/pic1.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic1.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic1_reduced.jpg) &
```

directly in the shell, it does not tie up the terminal but appears to run exactly as I want - as two sequential background tasks.

So how do I trigger this sequence of tasks from PHP to run sequentially as background tasks in the shell?

Edit: oh, as a nasty hack I tried to add a `sleep 10&&` like so:

```
shell_exec('(wget -bq -O /tmp/pic1.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& sleep 10&& convert /tmp/pic1.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic1_reduced.jpg) &');
```

...figuring that if it isn't done in 10s it's basically failed anyway and I will later know it's failed because the file isn't there.

But apparently that hangs PHP for 10 seconds, even though `sleep 10&` does run in the background if you try it in the shell. I guess I'm missing something here about how background tasks work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I cracked it. You still need to direct the output to /dev/null like so:

```
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic1.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic1.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic1_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

This seems to now produce the behaviour I wanted, .e.g a labour-intensive set of commands like this:

```
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic1.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic1.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic1_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic2.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic2.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic2_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic3.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic3.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic3_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic4.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic4.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic4_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic5.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic5.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic5_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic6.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic6.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic6_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
shell_exec('(wget -q -O /tmp/pic7.jpg https://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/APL/uploads/2014/10/nyan-cat-01-625x450.jpg&& convert /tmp/pic7.jpg -quality 80 -interlace Plane -resize 180x\> /tmp/pic7_reduced.jpg) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

...does not tie up PHP, but returns immediately, after a time producing the following output in the /tmp folder:

[screenshot of /tmp folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGEdd.png)